# Problem with Normals - pointed appearance

Tags: normals

Im unfamilliar to Blender's more advanced setting/glitches so i do not know how to title this question (i'll fix that later) but the normals (is this how its called or face direction?) suddenly started to look like the picture below (i dont know when it started doing this)

the problem only happens with the "normal" normals, the inverted normals are fine, unfortunately this problem also shows in renders, please help

[image]

Comment: UPload an example file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the normals are inverted, try this: 
Hit (Tab) to enter edit mode, (T) to show tools, go to "Shading/UVs" tab, hit the buttons Normal: (calculate) then (flip direction).

Comment: that is not the problem, i think its another setting i just dont know what, if you will invert the normals, it should show you a concave appearance of the normal normals, not a pointed or edged appearance, or is that just my misconception?

Comment: ah ok, its the screw modifier that is causing the thing

Answer (score 1):

if you are in Blender 2.8, you could visualize your normals with the OverlayTab-> Show Split Normals and if you see doubled normals pointing in different directions from one Vertex as in Picture 1 you can hit Alt-N and merge the normals to one direction (Picture 2)… maybe this helps.

[image: Splited Normals][image]